# Custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` for spring-dsl

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml, spring-dsl

Is there a way to add custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` when configuring through `SamlConfigurer` in spring dsl.
I want to add a JWT token on successful authentication.

Note: I see a [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml-dsl/pull/62/commits/1edd0e333ecebbd523d85978d382ee114d8b0e35) which is not merged and it is what I looking for. But is there any workaround for now?